# how to spacely give the image or text background in complex screen

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Hi friends I need to develop the screen like this one

[image: This the need layout I needed]

But I am getting below view I tried the expanded but varied differently please help friends I am new to flutter I am not getting any idea how to achieve the required layout

[image: It's My view]

Below is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'ColorsPage.dart';

void main() => runApp(new Login());

class Login extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    Login_State login_state() => Login_State();
    return login_state();
  }
}

class Login_State extends State<Login>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Builder(builder: (BuildContext context){
          return new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                  child: new Image.asset('assets/rural_post_logo.png'),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white
                ),
                alignment: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
              ),
              new Container(
                child: new Text('SIGN IN',style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white
                ),),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: secondarycolor
                ),
                alignment: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
              ),
              new Container(
                child: new Text('SIGN UP',style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white
                ),),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: primarycolor
                ),
                alignment: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
              )

            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Column` widget over the `Container` overwrites its normal behavior to be as big as possible and now it just wraps it's content as you noticed. You could give the `Container` a height `property` or wrap it in a `Padding`:

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(70.0),
        child: 
          new Container(
              child: new Image.asset('assets/rural_post_logo.png'),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white
            ),
            alignment: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
          ),
    ),
    new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
            child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
            child: new Text(
                'SIGN IN',
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: secondarycolor),
            alignment: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
        ),
        new Container(
            child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
            child: new Text(
                'SIGN UP',
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: primarycolor),
            alignment: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
        )
        ],
    ),
    ],
),
```

[image]

Comment: With `FlutterIcon`

Comment: can u tell me how ?

Comment: @ayubbaba `FlutterLogo( size: 50.0),`